# Change nested object data with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to affect all items in the array. The end result will be to `decodeURIcomponent` on each item.

It's not working for me so I decided to change the value of each item to check the code. It doesn't change anything.

Is there a better way of doing this, as really nested `$.each` functions seems a bit redundant to me.

```js
$(function() {

var hResponse = [];
hResponse.push("firstName", "lastName", "location");

var columns = [];
columns.push({
    "firstName": "Edward",
        "lastName": "Dane",
        "location": " Here"
}, {
    "firstName": "Arthur",
        "lastName": "Dee",
        "location": "There"
}, {
    "firstName": "Cherry",
        "lastName": "Red",
        "location": "OverHere"
});
$.each(columns, function (key, value) {

    $.each(value, function (key1, value2) {

        value2 = "Meeeeep";
        //value2 = decodeURIComponent(value2);
    });

});


$('#my-table').dynatable({
    dataset: {
        records: columns
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/dynatable-docs-assets/css/jquery.dynatable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/dynatable-docs-assets/js/jquery.dynatable.js"></script>

<table id="my-table">
    <thead>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<br>
```

Comment: `columns[key][key1] = "Meeeep";`

Comment: Sorry for being a pedant, but that's not JSON, it's just a javascript object

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oahypr9v/1/ Assign value to the object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript is all [*pass-by-value*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value). Assigning a value to a variable does not change the value of another variable or property (except in global and `with` scope). You have to assign the changed value back to the object property.

With minimal changes to your code:

```
$.each(columns, function (key, value) {
    $.each(value, function (key1, value2) {
        value[key] = decodeURIComponent(value2);
    });
});
```

Comment: `columns[key] === value`, and `value` is an object. Either way works.

Comment: Maybe it would be more appropriately called [call by sharing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/1896761)?

Comment: thanks so much, i usually rtfm, but i couldn't find any guides on accessing the object, specifically the [key] part , where can i find more info on this?

Comment: @Austin: yeah, but that term is not really used... I'm also not sure whether it's a good idea conflate strategies of passing data with strategies of representing data.

Comment: @platinums: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects, http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196